# VueJS : How to update value inside watcher without affecting the watcher

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I made an online quiz application using Vue in which each question has its own duration. I'm using watcher for the countdown and show it on the webpage. The problem I'm facing is every time I updated the time to match the next question's time, the countdown will end much sooner. What can I do to update the time limit in the watcher without interrupting the current countdown?

```js
watch: {
    timerEnabled(value) {
      if (value) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.timeLimit--;
        }, 1000);
      }
    },
    timeLimit: {
      handler(value) {
        if (value >= 0 && this.timerEnabled) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.timeLimit--;
          }, 1000);
        }
        else{
          // set the timer to the next question's time limit and move to the next question
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    timer: null,
    timerCounter: 0
  }
},
methods: {
  setTimer(state) { // true enabled, false disabled
    if(state) {
      this.timerCount = // seconds
      this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        timerCounter--;
        if(timerCounter <= 0) {
          this.setTimer(false);
          // go to next question
          this.setTimer(true);
        }
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }
  }
}
```

You only need to call `setTimer(true)` for start the timer for the first time, for example in the `mounted()` function or at click event of a button.

If you don't want that the timer restart after question change, remove `this.setTimer(true);`.

Comment: thank you for the answer, however I have some issues with timer outside of the watcher, that's why I am using a watcher instead